# How do i show UI in a standalone google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When building a bound google apps script I can use the following functions to show a ui to user.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Title');
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(ui);
```

However I get the following error when I try to run these functions in a standalone script:

```
Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.
```

I could find a way to show UI when running a standalone google apps script. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutput(String)

Comment: @Umair I have already created html output file. I need to showModalDialog next.

Comment: I think you'll need to do that using html for the same, as for standalone script google doesn't provide any element

Comment: The only way you can do this is if you deploy that script as a Spreadsheet add-on. This is not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by publishing your script as web app and returning your html output file in doGet function.

Add the following to your script

```
function doGet(e){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('file.html')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return html;
}
```

and then go to ***Publish->Deploy as web app***.